# java string-manipulations

Tags: java, string

Ok, so I tried with your help to learn a little bit more about strings and Chaining Strings in Java.

now I know that strings are  immutable, but I'm having a really hard time to do this ex:

> Implement the method
>
> ```
> public static String notReplace(String str)
> ```
>
> The method takes a String as its input
>   and returns a String in which every
>   occurrence of the lowercase word "is"
>   has been replaced with "is not". The
>   word "is" should not 2 be immediately
>   preceded or followed by a letter -- so
>   for example the "is" in "this"  should
>   not be replaced. (Note:
>   `Character.isLetter(char)` tests if a
>   char is a letter.)

**Examples:**
notReplace("is test") → "is not test"
notReplace("is-is wise") → "is not-is not wise"

This is what I wrote:

```
public class NotReplace{

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        final String str2 = "is no";
        System.out.println(notReplace(str2));

    }

    public static String notReplace(final String str){
        final int times = str.length();

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        for(int i = 0; i <= times; i++){
            if((str.charAt(i) == 'i') && (str.charAt(i + 1) == 's')
                && !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i + 2))){
                sb.insert(i, "not");

            }
            final String str1 = sb.toString();
            return str1;

        }
    }
}
```

I believe it is a complete mess, I'll be happy to learn more how to work with strings in situations like this.

Thanks

Edit: I can't use replaceAll function.

Comment: After I have repaired indentation you can see that the return statement needs to be moved after the next closing curly brace

Comment: As it stands you will get IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions with this code.

Comment: @Dave: yeah, I know. can you give me some hints to correct it?

Comment: `i<=times` is vastly incorrect

Comment: @everyone it's labeled 'homework' so it should not touch reg exp, please don't offer 'em

Comment: @DaveJohnston, there will NOT be out of bounds, due to return statement :D (there could be still for short strings starting w/ 'i')

Comment: @sean: still didn't figure out the "final"s.

Comment: sorry, you can delete those. I let my Eclipse always insert final keywords when possible, but they're not necessary

Comment: @Sean, you sure love finals, dunno why nowadays people love to add so much fluff in the code, imo it makes it harder to parse (by eyes) when overdone

Comment: @bestsss true, but it also documents the intent of not re-assigning variables which improves readibility

Comment: @Sean, if you do it automatic, it's just automatic, i mean it there is a bug and the value should be changed actually, it helps not.

Comment: @bestsss obviously. the best tools can't help you if you don't know your code :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take the following approach if I were you.

First step: think of as many strings that are "curious" as you can: `null, "", "i", "x", "is", "his", "ist", "list", "is it", "it is", "what is it", "what it is"` and so on.

Second step: write a `main()` method that feeds all these values to the `notReplace()` method and displays the result. The `notReplace()` method should simply return the parameter at this point.

```
public static String notReplace(final String str){
  return str;
}
```

Third step. Compile and test it. This is an important one. Don't write large chunks of code at once. Write a little, recompile it and check whether it still works. It sounds slow but it is much quicker than rooting around for hours trying to find a mismatched curly brace in 200 lines of code. From now on, between each step you should repeat this.

Fourth step: change `notReplace()` so that it finds the `"is"` substring. Don't alter the output, just do a `System.out.println( "Is found.");`.

Fifth step: extend it even further by detecting whether the preceding and the following character (if there is any) is a letter or not.

Sixth step: insert " not" after where you've found "is".

If you follow these steps, you will be able to build your program up gradually and because you modify only a couple of lines between two tests, any errors will be easy to find.

Answer (score 4):

You might find this interesting

```
String text = "This is a test. It is"; // note the 'is' at the end.
String text2 = text.replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "is not");
System.out.println(text +" => "+text2);
```

prints

```
This is a test. It is => This is not a test. It is not
```

The following method does this the long way

```
 public static String notReplace(final String str){
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
                                 .append(' ').append(str).append(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 2; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(sb.charAt(i)) &&
                sb.charAt(i + 1) == 'i' &&
                sb.charAt(i + 2) == 's' &&
                !Character.isLetter(sb.charAt(i + 3))) {
            sb.insert(i + 3, " not");
            i += 5;
        }
    }
    return sb.substring(1, sb.length() - 1);
}
```

Spaces are added to the start and end to avoid bounds checking.

Comment: Given that this is homework, I doubt OP would be allowed to use this.

Comment: Thanks peter, but I have to do that in the long way, I assume. I'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: Thank you.
1. you're using "insert" during the loop. How come it doesn't make a mess with the chacking?(or is this the reason that if the operand is true you add 5 to i?..)
2.strings, as arrays, start from 0?
3.For avoiding "is" in another words you added the initial operand that chacks whether the first char is not a letter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine , quiet complicated but

```
public String notReplace(String str) {

  String result = "";

  if(str.equals("is")) return "is not";


  for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

    if((i+2 < str.length() && str.substring(i,i+2).equals("is") 
    && !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i+2)) && (i==0 || !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i-1)) )))
    {//for is that are in between texts and at the start of the text
      result += str.substring(i,i+2) + " not";
      result+=str.charAt(i+2);

      i = i + 2;

    }
    else if(i == str.length()-2 && str.substring(i).equals("is") && !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i-1)) ){
        // for "is" at the end   
      result += str.substring(i,i+2) + " not";
      i = str.length();

    }
    else{// not a is
      result+= str.substring(i,i+1);
    }
  }
  return result;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem is sb.insert(i, "not"); should be sb.insert(i+1, " not ");
2. I think Regular Expression is a solution in such case.

Comment: The wording of the task implies that regular expressions shouldn't be used.

Comment: what do you mean by regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "This is a test";
String text2 = text.replaceAll(" is ", "is not");
System.out.println(text2);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I believe I cant use this in my h.w :)

Answer (score 0):

Me, I like recursive:

```
public static String notReplace(String str) {

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    notReplace(str, buffer);
    return buffer.toString();
}


public static void notReplace(String str, StringBuilder buffer) {
    if(str.length() < 3) {
        buffer.append(str).toString();
    }
    else if ( str.startsWith("is ") ) {
        notReplace(str.substring(3), buffer.append("is not "));         
    }
    else {
        notReplace(str.substring(1), buffer.append(str.charAt(0))); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public String notReplace(String str) {
  String outputStr = "";
  int index = 0;
  int lastSeen = 0;

  if (str == "is")
    return "is not";

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
    index = str.indexOf("is", lastSeen);
    if (index == -1)
      break;

    if (index == 0 && !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index + 2))) {
      outputStr = outputStr + str.substring(lastSeen, index);
      outputStr = outputStr + "is not";
      lastSeen = index + 2;
    } else if (index > 0 && index < str.length() - 2 && str.charAt(index + 2) == ' ' && str.charAt(index - 1) == ' ') {
      outputStr = outputStr + str.substring(lastSeen, index);
      outputStr = outputStr + "is not";
      lastSeen = index + 2;
    } else if (index == (str.length() - 2) && !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index - 1))) {
      outputStr = outputStr + str.substring(lastSeen, index);
      outputStr = outputStr + "is not";
      lastSeen = index + 2;
    } else {
      if (lastSeen < str.length()) {
        outputStr = outputStr + str.substring(lastSeen, index);
        outputStr = outputStr + "is";
      }
      lastSeen = index + 2;
    }

  }
  if (lastSeen < str.length())
    outputStr = outputStr + str.substring(lastSeen);
  return outputStr;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you think the first condition `if (str == "is")` is ever matching?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String notReplace(String str) {
String a  = "";
int i = 0;
if(str.length()<2)
  {return "";}
else if(str.length()==2 && (!(str.substring(0).equals("is"))))
  {return "";}
else if(str.length()==2)
{return "is "+"not";}
while(i<str.length()){
if(i==0&& str.substring(0,2).equals("is")&&Character.isLetter(str.charAt(2))==false)
{a+= str.substring(0,2)+" not";
i+=2;}
else if(i>1&&i<str.length()-2&&str.substring(i,i+2).equals("is")&&Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i-1))==false&&Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i+2))==false)
{a+= str.substring(i,i+2)+" not";i+=2;}
else if(i == str.length()-2 && str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("is")&&Character.isLetter(str.charAt(str.length()-3))==false)
{a+=str.substring(str.length()-2)+ " not";break;}
else
{a+= str.charAt(i);
i+=1;}
}
return a;
}
```

this might seem complex but i got this in first try.